# Code Runner extension of Visual Studio Code doesn't work when click in "Run Code"

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner, coderunner

When I click on every button of "Run Code" (top-right of windows or when right-click the code) or even when I type the key shortcut "Ctrl + Alt + N" (which is defined in settings) VSCode doesn't do anything, doesn't show any error but also doesn't run code.

I have been using Code Runner extension almost 1 year and it worked well, just from one day to another it stopped work.

Here's my settings.json file:
[my settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcPwa.png)

And my workspace.json:
[my workspace.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j2A4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change on your code-workspace

```
"folders": [
    {   
        "path": "."
    },
],
```